Secure install cursor.sh in Ubuntu 24.04
I tried to install cursor.sh in Ubuntu 24.04 but it doesn't work.   They give me a cursor-0.34.2x86_64.AppImage file but it doesn't run.
In their forum i found this post:
https://forum.cursor.sh/t/cursor-sh-install-ubuntu-24-04/4838
It sent me to another post:
https://github.com/getcursor/cursor/issues/844#issuecomment-2080288303
I did a profile with their instructions but at Ubuntu restart, my pc didn't boot and show me a ACPI error.   Then i had to reinstall Ubuntu.
Somebody knows how to secure install cursor.sh in the last Ubuntu version?

Good question for the github guys who are maintaining that.

Is this helpful?

Does this answer your question? How to safely install fuse on Ubuntu 22.04?

Here's what worked for me from beginning to end.

Install libfuse2t64 with sudo apt install libfuse2t64
Download the Cursor AppImage file from the official website
Navigate to the directory where the .AppImage file sits (e.g. Downloads)
Grant permissions with chmod +x cursor-0.39.5x86_64.AppImage (modify the version and platform to match your .AppImage file)
Move the file to the /opt directory while changing the file name to a more friendly one: sudo mv cursor-0.39.5x86_64.AppImage /opt/cursor.appimage
Create the desktop entry with sudo nano /usr/share/applications/app.desktop and add this to the file:

[Desktop Entry]
Name=Cursor
Exec=/opt/cursor.appimage
Icon=CHANGE THIS TO THE LOCATION OF YOUR ICON FILE (DOWNLOAD IT FROM THE INTERNET)
Type=Application
Categories=Development;


Fix the apparmor error with the script some user added on github with the path that matches our location, i.e. -> make the file at /etc/apparmor.d/cursor-appimage and add the following to it:

# This profile allows everything and only exists to give the
# application a name instead of having the label "unconfined"

abi <abi/4.0>,
include <tunables/global>

profile cursor /opt/cursor.appimage flags=(unconfined) {
  userns,

  # Site-specific additions and overrides.  See local/README for details.
  include if exists <local/cursor>
}


Run the parser with: sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/cursor-appimage


Excellent work!

could also run with /opt/cursor.appimage --no-sandbox to skip step 7

sudo apt install libfuse2 if you are on Ubuntu <24.04 :)

Thanks this is working, at last, my third times re-installing 24.04 because previously installing fuse.

Try this:
$ sudo apt install libfuse2
... then re-try running any AppImage.

In 24.04 it's libfuse2t64.

Strangely enough the above worked well on my newly installed 24.04

I created this script. I also created a gist to make it easier.
You can run only this.
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tatosjb/0ca8551406499d52d449936964e9c1d6/raw/eec8df843c35872ba3e590c7db5451af7e131906/install-cursor-sh | bash
https://gist.github.com/tatosjb/0ca8551406499d52d449936964e9c1d6
#!/bin/bash

# To install on ubuntu
# curl -fsSL https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tatosjb/0ca8551406499d52d449936964e9c1d6/raw/254665b405d8fa9a8bb4e69e1605119bdb376aa0/install-cursor-sh | bash

installCursor() {
    if ! [ -f /opt/cursor.appimage ]; then
        echo "Installing Cursor AI IDE..."
        mkdir -p ~/Applications/cursor
        # URLs for Cursor AppImage and Icon
        APPIMAGE_URL="https://downloader.cursor.sh/linux/appImage/x64"
        ICON_URL="https://global.discourse-cdn.com/flex020/uploads/cursor1/original/2X/f/f7bc157cca4b97c3f0fc83c3c1a7094871a268df.png"

        # Paths for installation
        APPDIR="$HOME/Applications/cursor"
        APPIMAGE_PATH="$APPDIR/cursor.AppImage"
        ICON_PATH="$APPDIR/cursor-icon.png"
        UPDATE_SCRIPT_PATH="$APPDIR/update-cursor.sh"
        DESKTOP_ENTRY_PATH="/usr/share/applications/cursor.desktop"

        # Install curl if not installed
        echo "curl is not installed. Installing..."
        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt-get install -y wget dbus-x11 update-notifier

        # Download Cursor AppImage
        echo "Downloading Cursor AppImage..."
        wget -O $APPIMAGE_PATH "$APPIMAGE_URL"
        sudo chmod +x $APPIMAGE_PATH
        sudo ln -s ~/Applications/cursor/cursor.AppImage /usr/local/bin/cursor

        # Download Cursor icon
        echo "Downloading Cursor icon..."
        wget -O $ICON_PATH "$ICON_URL"

        # Create a .desktop entry for Cursor
        echo "Creating .desktop entry for Cursor..."
        sudo bash -c "cat > $DESKTOP_ENTRY_PATH" <<EOL
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Cursor
Exec=$APPIMAGE_PATH --no-sandbox
Icon=$ICON_PATH
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Development;
EOL

        bash -c "cat > $UPDATE_SCRIPT_PATH" <<EOL
#!/bin/bash

APPDIR=$APPDIR
APPIMAGE_URL=$APPIMAGE_URL

wget -O \$APPDIR/cursor.AppImage \$APPIMAGE_URL
chmod +x \$APPDIR/cursor.AppImage
EOL
        chmod +x $UPDATE_SCRIPT_PATH

        mkdir -p ~/.config/systemd/user
        bash -c "cat > $HOME/.config/systemd/user/update-cursor.service" << EOL
[Unit]
Description=Update Cursor

[Service]
ExecStart=$UPDATE_SCRIPT_PATH
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
EOL

        eval $(dbus-launch --sh-syntax)

        systemctl --user enable update-cursor.service
        systemctl --user start update-cursor.service

        echo "export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=\"/run/user/\$(id -u)\"" >> $HOME/.zshrc
        echo "export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=\"unix:path=\${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/bus\"" >> $HOME/.zshrc

        echo "
Cursor AI IDE installation complete. You can find it in your application menu.

PLEASE REBOOT YOUR SYSTEM TO MAKE SURE THAT EVERYTHING WAS SET UP PROPERLY
"
    else
        echo "Cursor AI IDE is already installed."
    fi
}

installCursor

